# Adding hover state to sibling

Tags: html, css

I have an image that has a hover state that changes two things: it darkens the image and it displays absolute positioned text over the image. The issue I'm having is when I hover over the text the image is no longer showing darkened. I've tried adding a hover state to the text as well. The image and hover text are siblings so I tried using the ~ following-sibling combinator like this: `.hovertext:hover ~ .hoverimg` but obviously I'm not using it correctly.

Code

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.hovertext {
  display: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.wrapper:hover .hovertext {
  display: block;
}

.hoverimg:hover,
.hovertext:hover~.hoverimg {
  filter: brightness(50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="hoverimg" src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240">
  <div class="hovertext">HOVER TEXT</div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to show both hover states with CSS only?

Comment: are you ok with using css content: "HOVER TEXT"; rather than having the text in your HTML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `pointer-events:none` to the text if there is no hover or click event on text

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.hovertext {
  display: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.wrapper:hover .hovertext {
  display: block;
}

.hoverimg:hover,
.hovertext:hover~.hoverimg {
  filter: brightness(50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="hoverimg" src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240">
  <div class="hovertext">HOVER TEXT</div>
</div>
```

And if you are planning to add event on the text then you can change `img` and `text` properties on `.wrapper` class hover

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.hovertext {
  display: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.wrapper:hover .hovertext {
  display: block;
}

.wrapper:hover .hoverimg {
  filter: brightness(50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="hoverimg" src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240">
  <div class="hovertext">HOVER TEXT</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! But I do plan on having a click event as well if anywhere is clicked within the wrapper (image or text).

Comment: then maybe try <a class="wrapper" href="...></a> and then set a.wrapper to display: block; and then this solution should be pretty good.

Comment: @Davyd I have added the second solution without `pointer-events:none`...

Comment: thanks @Bhuwan learned something new today that has plagued me for many years!

Comment: I actually just tried this on my site and my jQuery click event appears to still be working. I need to read up on what pointer-events are. Thank you Bhuwan!

Comment: @Davyd I have applied `pointer-events:none` on the text...click event will not work on text but will work on image...

Comment: Here is an updated version with a click event. I guess this is working because the click event is on the parent and not the .hovertext?
 This should work for my needs as you can still click on the image or text. https://jsfiddle.net/9z0mu2nm/6/

Comment: @Davyd yeah...but if you use `$('.hovertext').on('click')`..it will not work...then you have to use second option...

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of selecting the previous element i.e. changing the styling of previous element using CSS as you are trying using sibling selector `.hovertext:hover ~ .hoverimg`, to make use of `sibling selector` here you need to make some changes in your html markup as below,

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.hovertext {
  display: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 9;
}

.wrapper:hover > .hovertext {
  display: block;
}

.hoverimg:hover,
.hovertext:hover ~ .hoverimg {
  filter: brightness(50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="hovertext">HOVER TEXT</div>
  <img class="hoverimg" src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240">
</div>
```

In the above codes I have changed your HTML markup, thus now `.hoverimg` is sibling of targeted element i.e. `.hovertext`, so now every-time when you hover .`hovertext` or `.hoverimg` it adds assigned styling.

Comment: Use of sibling selector was not needed here, the same would have worked if you used parent and child selector (>) as in this jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cvoao938/